# preview an image while requesting another one from url windows phone 8

Tags: windows-phone-8

i need to preview default image while getting my exact image from a url 
here's my code for getting the image

```
Uri uri = new Uri(myUrl);
            Profile.Source = new BitmapImage(uri);
```

"Profile" is the Image that previews the requested image

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use two images. The first one will be the placeholder you want, and the second one will be the profile picture that will show up later and cover the first one.

You need these images to be in the same palce, one above the other. You can user `Grid` to achieve that.

```xml
<Grid>
    <Image x:Name="Placeholder" Source="/Assets/Placeholder.png" />
    <Image x:Name="Profile" ImageOpened="Profile_ImageOpened" />
</Grid>
```

The *Placeholder.png* is an image that has been added to the project.

Now, we want to know, when profile picture is download. Event `ImageOpened` gives us the way. We can use it to hide the placeholder when the profile picture is fully downloaded.

```cs
private void Profile_ImageOpened(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Placeholder.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
}
```